# unable to send files via scp

Tags: scp

I have a root privilege for two different hosts. However I am not able to send a file from one host to another host via scp command. What is the issue? Kindly help me.

Here is the command which I used and its output

```
      scp -vr cvschangelogbuilder_zivah_miscellaneous* root@192.168.1.11:/var/www/cvsreport/images/ZIVAH.zivah_miscs
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 192.168.1.11, user root, command scp -v -r -d -t -- /var/www/cvsreport/images/ZIVAH.zivah_miscs
OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.11 [192.168.1.11] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3p2 Debian-5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3p2 Debian-5 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '192.168.1.11' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@192.168.1.11's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_IN
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -d -t -- /var/www/cvsreport/images/ZIVAH.zivah_miscs
=================== SUPER USER Login; Please Take Care  ==================
GitServer:~# debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 1864, received 2456 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6134.7, received 8083.1
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Comment: show us the error or the behaviour you are having...

Comment: Maybe root is not allowed to login remotely? You should provide some error messages. Or what do you meen with "I am not able"? Did you try turning on your computer? Connect to Wi-Fi? etc.? … … …

Comment: @logoff I have edited my post with the command which I used and its output

Comment: I can't see any error. So the files aren't transferred at all? Did you try transferring only one file for testing?

Comment: @thillaiselvan it seems all OK, no errors. have you checked the remote system for the files?

Comment: @logoff yes. I have checked and found that I haven't received these files :(

Comment: @thillaiselvan try to send a single file, not a folder recursively as septi says.

Comment: @logoff Now I have sent a single file alone. This time also I haven't received the file in the other server

Comment: @thillaiselvan if no errors are reported your file should be there. double-check the folders, the files and the IP addresses please. additionally, using root user is not recommended.

Comment: @logoff In the destination server I have executed and in ls -lrt ( even ls -lrta ) command's output I haven't seen these files.

Comment: @thillaiselvan the files are sent OK, for suer. SCP did not fail to check it. then I can only say, you are checking bad it or for some mysterious reason the files were removed... I can not help more, there are no errors on the transmission.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the similar problem. That is I have `scp` exit with 0, but the file is not transported.

And I have found the thread as a bug [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20527).  And a explanation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18231/scp-fails-without-error).

The problem is with the `echo` command in two files `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`. The `scp` startup with a non-interactive shell and read the data from it. As the non-interactive shell will read the two configuration files. Their output together with the out put from the `scp` will confuse `scp` and thus no files output.

I examined your output and see that there are a line:

> =================== SUPER USER Login; Please Take Care  ==================

remove the `echo` command or add

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- == *i* ]] || return
```

to prevent the problem.